# In cakephp Jquery ajax get not working in chrome.

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am using cakephp 2.4, here I have used bellow code to send the search value to ReportsContrller in searchdue methods.

```
           $('.search').keyup(function(){
                var search=$('.search').val();
                console.log(search);
                $.get("<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Reports','action'=>'searchdue'));?>",
                       {'search':search},
                       function(data){
                          $('.backsearch').html(data);
                       }
                      )
           })
```

Then in searchdue method I have written bellow code

```
public function searchdue()
    {
        if(isset($this->request->query['search'])){
            $search = $this->request->query['search'];

        }
        else{
                $search = '';
            }
        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'conditions' => array('Report.id LIKE' => "$search"),
            'limit'=>1
        );
        $this->set('reports',$this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
```

Without firefox this code is not supporting other browsers.Here Keyup event working fine but data is not sending to method.

Comment: You should echo data in searchdue() as you get it in return as AJAX result from cakephp!!!

Comment: view template is generating but without data.

Comment: use `$this->request->params['search']` instead of your $this->request on 1st,2nd line.

Comment: in your function , use echo "<pre>";print_r($search); What ajax result you get ?

Comment: Here I have not any get result, here search value is not sending.

Comment: Try using `$this->layout = 'ajax'` as 1st line in your Controller function.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action, after setting variables to view you can add following lines:

```
public function searchdue() {
    // (...)
    $this->set('reports',$this->Paginator->paginate());

    $this->layout = null;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $content = $this->render();
    die($content->body());
}
```

To ensure that everything is correctly returned you can also use `json_encode();` before you finish your action by `die();`.

So last two lines you can change into:

```
// (...)
$content = $this->render()->body();
$result = array('content' => $content);
die(json_encode($result));
```

Then you have to also change a little bit your ajax call:

```
$.get("<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Reports','action'=>'searchdue'));?>", {'search':search}, function(data) {
   $('.backsearch').html(data.content);
}, 'json');
```